# GitHub ifrogs package installation failed

Tags: package

To calculate the default proxy "distance to default" (DTD) in my research paper on credit risk, I need to download the "[ifrogs](https://github.com/xKDR/ifrogs)" package, however there are some problems so I can't install the package successfully.

The code is as follow:

```
library(devtools)
install.packages("fOptions", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

When I run the code, the following error message pops up:

```
ERROR: dependency 'fOptions' is not available for package 'ifrogs'
* removing 'C:/Users/Asus/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/ifrogs'
Warning messages:
1: package ‘fOptions’ is not available for this version of R
```

From my understanding, the installation failure seems to be due to the inability to access the "fOptions" package. After searching online, it appears that "fOptions" might not be usable for some reasons. I would like to ask if there's a solution to this issue or if anyone can recommend an alternative package similar to "ifrogs" for calculating DTD? Thanks in advance for everyone's assistance!

Comment: This package has been out of development for at least 6 years.